# Trying to link to a php template file but its blank

Tags: theme-development, themes

[From this Stack Overflow qestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810124/how-can-i-add-a-php-page-to-wordpress) It shows a bunch of ways to make page templates. But I don't want to use a page template that uses Gutenberg.
Is there another way to make a PHP file like a tos.php, and link to it by
`<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/tos.php'; ?>`
I tried to link the page that way but gives be a blank page.

```
    <?php 
    /* Template Name: ghfjghjg*/

    get_header();
    ?>

    <main id="primary" class="site-main main-header">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor    incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    </main><!-- #main -->

    <?php
    get_footer();
```

Also tried, adding this to my functions.php.

```
function include_TOS() {
    return  __DIR__ . 'tos.php';

}
apply_filters( 'template_include', 'include_TOS' );
```

Comment: what are you trying to do that requires this? `esc_html_e` is an escaping/localisation function, it's not a way to load and output files. It's unclear what you want to do or why you want to do it, use the edit link underneath the tags to improve and update your question.

Comment: are you sure because I got esc_html_e from the underscores template? And I added more.

Comment: The Link I posted is not what I want I just want to link to the file in my theme. Is there another way?

Comment: You shouldn't be using variables in `esc_html_e`, that function does not do what you think it does. Are you trying to create a `example.com/tos` page by putting a `tos.php` file in your theme? `echo` does not include a file, it just prints out a string of text, in this case the location of the file. Also you don't use `apply_filters` to add a filter, you use `add_filter`

Comment: Tried `add_filter` and `add_action` still blank page?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to tell you, Yes "Are you trying to create `a example.com/tos` page by putting a `tos.php` file in your theme?" Is it not possible?

Comment: indeed, it is not possible, that's not how PHP theme templates work. The absolute closest you could get is a `page-tos.php` that would load for a page with the slug `tos`. Otherwise you would need to build a rewrite rule and a virtual page which would involves multiple filters, and is not simple to do. I know you want to save yourself a step but you're actually taking something that takes 5 minutes and turning it into 5 hours of work plus more of research

Answer (score 0):

[`get_header()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_header/) and [`get_footer()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_footer/) are WordPress functions, not native PHP. If the code snippet you've posted is the entire content of `tos.php`, you're not loading WordPress at all, the functions don't exist, and so `tos.php` is throwing a fatal error. It's likely that your web host is configured to *not* display fatal errors, so you see an entirely blank page.

Further: Gutenberg is an editor, and shouldn't affect the display of pages on the front end. If you're trying to specify that a given post or page should use your `tos.php` template, you should have a look at the [`template_include`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/) filter.

Comment: From the link, you posted there are some comments on how to use it. Do I need a function for it to work? Or just add it somewhere(You didn't say where) will make the link work on the home page of my site.

Comment: I updated the question.